# how to use intField to set a values into a variable

Tags: python, maya

introducing that I'm new in python, I'm tring to use the **intField** command to set a number of iterations for this attribute: 'aiSubdivIterations'.

The script should work like that: when I run the scripts it open a window where I can set my value and when I press enter it should automatically set the same value in the 'aiSubdivIterations' slot.

```
import maya.cmds as pm

def aiSetIter(iterValue):   
    objSelect= pm.ls(sl=1, dag=True, leaf=True)
    for obj in objSelect:
        pm.setAttr( obj + '.aiSubdivIterations', iterValue)

pm.window(title = 'Interations')
pm.columnLayout ('mainColumn', adjustableColumn = True)
pm.gridLayout ('nameGridLayout01', numberOfRowsColumns = (2,2), cellWidthHeight = (80,30), parent = 'mainColumn')
pm.text (label = 'number')
pm.intField (minValue=0, maxValue=10, step=1, vcc = 'aiSetIter(iterValue)')
pm.showWindow()
```

Could some one help to make this script working?

Thanks in advance

Flavia

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: # Error: line 1: NameError: file <maya console> line 1: name 'iterValue' is not defined #

Comment: `iterValue` you directly passed `pm.intField (minValue=0, maxValue=10, step=1, vcc = 'aiSetIter(iterValue)')`, not get defined in your code

Comment: yes, I see. So I change my question, how can I connect the value which I've chosen in the intField with the settAttr aiSubdivIterations?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest for your script to work is to just specify the function you want to call (with no arguments and the rest of your code unchanged):

```
pm.intField('valueField', minValue=0, maxValue=10, step=1, vcc=aiSetIter)
```

You can assume that Maya's intField will call the specified function by automatically passing the value it stores.
In the above case, your function will be [called only when the UI is made visible or closed](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/intField.html#flagvisibleChangeCommand).

If you need your function to be called every time the value changes, you want to add a ["changeCommand" (or "cc") flag](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/intField.html#flagchangeCommand) too:

```
pm.intField('valueField', minValue=0, maxValue=10, step=1, vcc=aiSetIter, cc=aiSetIter)
```

For more complex scenarios, you might want to consider *lambda functions* (you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890188/8200213) a nice post about it); this will allow delayed evaluation of your function.
What follows is a super-simple example of a *lambda function* retrieving the current time when the intField value changes and passing it, along with the value itself, to *myLambdaFunc*:

```
import maya.cmds as pm
import time

def myLambdaFunc(iterValue, now):
    print iterValue, now

lambdafunc = lambda arg: myLambdaFunc(arg, time.time())

pm.window(title='Iterations')
pm.columnLayout ('mainColumn', adjustableColumn=True)
pm.gridLayout ('nameGridLayout01', numberOfRowsColumns=(2,2), cellWidthHeight=(80,30), parent='mainColumn')
pm.text (label='number')
pm.intField('valueField', minValue=0, maxValue=10, step=1, vcc=lambdafunc, cc=lambdafunc)
pm.showWindow(win)
```

EDIT:

A minor integration, since I bumped into this just now:
https://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet

It is a useful and exhaustive article by [theodox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1936075/theodox) about Maya UI and callbacks, found via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753094/maya-python-ui-local-variable-not-defined-error-when-used-inside-button-comman); worth a read.