# Maya python UI - local variable not defined error when used inside button command within same function

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I'm learning how to build UI for maya in native python,(not Tkinter). the following code works just fine, creates a window with a button which when pressed prints 'bar' to the history output:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.window(title='Basic UI')
cmds.columnLayout()
foo = 'bar'
cmds.button(label = 'foobar', command = 'print(foo)')

cmds.showWindow()
```

But if i put the same code in a function buildIt():

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def buildIt():
    cmds.window(title='Basic UI')
    cmds.columnLayout()
    foo = 'bar'
    cmds.button(label = 'foobar', command = 'print(foo)')

    cmds.showWindow()

buildIt()
```

The window builds fine but upon activating the button I get:

```
Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 1: name 'foo' is not defined
```

What is happening here? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the first sample in the listener, `foo` is defined in the global scope so it's available when the callback fires. In the second example it's defined in the scope of the function -- so it's not available when the callback fires in the global scope.

This will work:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def buildIt():
    cmds.window(title='Basic UI')
    cmds.columnLayout()
    foo = 'bar'
    def print_foo(*_):
        print foo
    cmds.button(label = 'foobar', command = print_foo)

    cmds.showWindow()

buildIt()
```

The difference here is that we pass the function `print_foo` directly, not as a string. So, Maya captures its value when the button is created and saves it (this is known as a [closure](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures), and it's super useful).  This ensures that the function can be used when the callback is actually used.

In general, avoid using the string version of callbacks -- they are a holdover from MEL and they always result in exactly the problem you're seeing.

More detail [here](https://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet)

Comment: Perfect explanation, thank you. Also those links are super helpful.